# Difference between Objects.hashCode() and new Object().hashCode()?

Tags: java, java-7, hashcode

What's the difference between these two code snippets?

Snippet 1:

```
Object o = new Object();
int i = Objects.hashCode(o);
```

Snippet 2:

```
Object o = new Object();
int i = o.hashCode();
```

Comment: `java.util.Objects` since 1.7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Tolerates null value

The only difference is that if o is null, `Objects.hashCode(o)` returns 0 whereas `o.hashCode()` would throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Objects is a class with hashCode being a static method in it.

Comment: @Apurv See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) (since 1.7).

Comment: @ArjunRao: So, assuming there are no `null` objects, they're just the same?

Comment: No since `Objects.hashCode(o)` has an additional logic to determine if o is null. If you're sure o is not null, it is marginally (negligibly) better to use `o.hashCode()`.

Answer (score 4):

This is how [`Objects.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) is implemented:

```
public static int hashCode(Object o) {
    return o != null ? o.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

If `o` is `null` then `Objects.hashCode(o);` will return `0`, whereas `o.hashCode()` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.util.Objects {
    public static int hashCode(Object o) {
        return o != null ? o.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

This is a NPE safe alternative to o.hashCode().

No difference otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object o = new Object();
int i = Objects.hashCode(o);
```

It returns the hash code of a not-null argument and 0 for
     null argument. This case it is `Object` referred by `o`.It doesn't throw `NullPointerException`.

```
Object o = new Object();
int i = o.hashCode();
```

Returns the hashCode() of `Object` referred by `o`. If `o` is `null` , then  you will get a `NullPointerException`.