# Objects.hashCode versus Object::hashCode in Java 7 and later

Tags: java, hashcode

Java 7 added the [`java.util.Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class with several utility methods. One of these, [`Objects.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object)) returns a `int` hash value for the single passed `Object`.

What is the point of this particular method?

How is this different than just calling the superclass method [`Object::hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) on the original object?

Comment: Well, it does have some null checking: The body of `Objects.hashcode(Object o)` is essentially: `return o != null ? o.hashCode() : 0`

Comment: Yes, my Question here is indeed a duplicate of [*Difference between Objects.hashCode() and new Object().hashCode()?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16187453/642706). That original escaped my searches. Thanks. And the answer is indeed tolerating NULL as commented above.